# Wix Burn Will not Uninstall package because of dependents

Tags: wix, uninstallation, burn

I am building a installer using Burn (Wix 3.8). Sometimes, uninstall cannot be done because of "Found dependent"s. If I remove these dependent registry, the problem will be solved. However, this make inconvenience when deploying application.

Does Wix BootstrapperApplication support any method to overcome this issue? If not, I can delete these registry by code. Which event of BootstrapperApplication detect these dependents?

Thank you in advance.